# Swift vDSP_create_fftsetup deprecated in iOS 8.4?

Tags: swift, fft, accelerate-framework, vdsp, ios8.4

I am using some FFT routine I wrote for another application in Swift a couple of months ago.

The line initializing the FFT setup, i.e. calculating the weights of the FFT,

```
let fft_weights: FFTSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(17, FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))
```

does not seem to work anymore for iOS 8.4, whereas the former app works fine on iOS 8.3. When I try to type the function, it doesn't appear anymore. Is it deprecated? If yes, since it's a very relevant function, what is the substitute?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that you imported Accelerate with `import Accelerate` ? The probability for it being removed is negligible

Comment: I just tried it out with iOS 9 in a playground and it's there for sure, autocomplete and everything

Comment: @Kametrixom Yes I used `import Accelerate` (the other functions of vDSP would not be available if I didn't, but they are in the autocomplete), so I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Do you actually get an error when you compile, or is it simply not appearing with autocomplete?

Comment: @StephenCanon, I formerly got both, i.e. an error at compilation and then no autocomplete. I tried in Playground, which had an error as well, then I added a device and then the Playground, the autocomplete and the compilation worked all fine. Which still does not explain what it was working on the application I wrote months ago and not on the present one. But anyways, the problem is now solved.

Comment: To formally answer your question: no it is not deprecated. =)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with several FFT functions online. Turns out you need to prepend the functions with vDSP_. I see you have that on your function call "vDSP_create_fftsetup" so likely not the same problem. Just want to point it out for other people with similar problems.